# sed on variable to extract filenumber

Tags: shell, sed, csh

Hello I have a variable in Csh var and it contains a file path.
`echo $var` it gives output like
`File232 = /path/path/path`
I want to store into another variable but I want to extract just the number 232. I tried
`echo $var | sed s -i s/ *//g`
But it didnt do the job instead it removed spaces before and after =.
I was thinking I will get File232 and try to extract 232 then.

Comment: if it's really `file232...`, then just perform 2 substitutions that delete what you don't need, i.e.`set var = "File232 = /path/path/path"; echo "$var" | sed 's/^File//;s/ = .*$//'` . I don't have a `csh` handy to test with, but this should work. Note that your code with `sed s -i` should cause an error; even removing that extra `s`, then you don't need `-i` because you're not writing to a physical file, you're reading and writing to stdin/stdout . Good luck.

Comment: Thanks I will try this as well. I figured the problem. set varnew = `echo $var|sed  's/ .*//g'`; @ number = `echo $varnew | sed 's/File//'

Answer (score 1):

Well you could do something like this for numbers between 1 to 5 digits length. If you have longer numbers then increase the second number in the curly brackets or replace the curly brackets by a star.

```
echo $var | sed -n 's/[^0-9]*\([0-9]\{1,5\}\) =.*/\1/p'
echo $var | sed -n 's/[^0-9]*\([0-9]\{1,10\}\) =.*/\1/p'
echo $var | sed -n 's/[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\) =.*/\1/p'
```

Or, if you have all your vars in a file. Let's say it looks like this and is called data.txt.

```
File234 = /path/to/somfile
Dir9892 = /path/to/somfile
File93849 = /path/to/somfile
File239 = /path/to/somfile
File9999 = /path/to/somfile
File+1 = /path/to/somfile
File_54980 = /path/to/somfile
```

You could do:

```
sed -n 's/[^0-9]*\([0-9]\{1,5\}\) =.*/\1/p' data.txt
```

and get:

```
234
9892
93849
239
9999
1
54980
```